# Callable<T> substitute that can pass parameters

Tags: java

I have a lot of code that every function starts and ends in the same way. So I started using the Callable to make it more clear. But what I want to do is somehow get the "check" object to each of the functions (foo/doo/roo) but the call method wont allow to send parameters. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public void foo(String something, Boolean flag, Object obj) {
    callSafe(something, flag, () => /*some code capturing obj*/);
}

public void doo(String something, Boolean flag) {
    callSafe(something, flag, () => /*different code using check*/);
}

public void roo(String something, Boolean flag, Integer id) {
    callSafe(something, flag, () => /*some code using check*/);
}

private void callSafe(string something, Boolean flag, Callable<T> c) {
    try {
        Object check = someFunction(flag, something);
        if (check.IsTrue()) {
            c.call(); 
            //c.call(check); //What I want to do.
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

I suppose that I could just run "someFunction" twice (once in the callable and once in the actual function) but the function is slow and I wouldn't want to do that.

Edit: Fixed it by adding an interface and by using the approach @Eran suggested. The interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedFunction<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws Exception;
}
```

I am not sure though if this is good practice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `Callable` is suitable in the first place, since the `call` method returns a value, which you ignore.

You can use a `Consumer<SomeClass>`, which has an `accept(SomeClass t)` method.

```
private void callSafe(String something, Boolean flag, Consumer<SomeClass> c) {
    try {
        SomeClass check = someFunction(flag, something);
        if (check.IsTrue()) {
            c.accept (check);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}

public void roo(String something, Boolean flag, Integer id) {
    callSafe(something, flag, (SomeClass check) -> /*some code using check*/);
}
```

If you do need a returned value, you can use a `Function<T, R>`, which has a `R apply(T t)` method:

```
private void callSafe(String something, Boolean flag, Function<SomeClass,ReturnClass> f) {
    try {
        SomeClass check = someFunction(flag, something);
        if (check.IsTrue()) {
            f.apply (check);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}

public void roo(String something, Boolean flag, Integer id) {
    callSafe(something, flag, (SomeClass check) -> /*some code using check which return an instance of ReturnClass*/);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get an "Incompatible types" error, when I use SomeClass in both places.

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff Can you show an example of what an actual lambda expression looks like? The problem is probably in the "/*some code using check*/" part.

Comment: the lambda expression returns some values, i think that that's what giving me problems

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff Since in your example you are not doing anything with the value returned by the original `Callable` you were using, I assumed you didn't need a return value. Therefore the lambda shouldn't return a value. If you need a returned value, use the `Function` interface instead of `Consumer`.

Comment: The Function<T,R>?

Comment: The Function<T,R> will not be able to handle exceptions though.

Comment: Yeah, judging by previous questions, the reason OP is using `Callable` rather than `Runnable` is checked exceptions.

Comment: @Eran I fixed it by adding an interface

     `@FunctionalInterface
      public interface CheckedFunction<T, R> {
             R apply(T t) throws Exception;
        }`
But I am not sure if this is good practice or not.

Comment: @slim Lambdas _can_ throw checked exceptions, just not expression-bodied lambdas (which is the case for unchecked exceptions too).  For example, this is perfectly valid: `Callable<Void> x = () -> { throw new Exception(); };`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel - just tested, and you're right. I'm sure I've failed to do this before. Comment deleted.

Comment: @Slim I don’t recall whether the method declaring the lambda has to add the exception to its `throws` list, but I’m pretty sure IntelliJ flagged the `throw` statement with an error if you didn’t, whether it was actually required or not.  Maybe that’s what you were remembering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way.

You should be looking into the Aspect-Oriented Programming. If you're using Spring, it should be rather painless to integrate Spring's runtime proxies for your task.

You will need to create the aspect which will wrap your functions, create an annotation to mark the functions (must be Spring components with public methods from component's interface), configure the aspect.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html for details.

This seems to be a simple example-driven introduction in Spring's runtime aspects: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-aop-example.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it you want a `Consumer<CheckResult>`:

```
 Consumer<CheckResult> c = result -> doSomethingWith(result);
```

However your need to use checked exceptions gets in the way of this -- `Consumer.accept()` can't throw a checked `Exception`.

You could write your own `ThrowingCheckResultConsumer` interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingCheckResultConsumer {
     void accept(CheckResult obj) throws MyException;
}
```

... or more generically:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T,E extends Exception> {
     void accept(T obj) throws E;
}
```

The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation tells Java that a lambda can be used as an implementation of this interface.

Now you can implement one:

```
    ThrowingCheckResultConsumer c = cr -> doSomethingWith(cr);
    c.accept("");
```

Or in your circumstance:

```
callSafe(something, flag, cr -> doSomethingWith(cr));
```

... and

```
private void callSafe(String something, Boolean flag, ThrowingCheckResultConsumer consumer) {
    try {
        SomeClass check = someFunction(flag, something);
        if (check.IsTrue()) {
            consumer.accept(check);
        }
    } catch(MyException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

In your question you catch `Exception`. I've used `MyException`, because broadly catching `Exception` is generally considered bad style. Only catch `RuntimeException` and the checked exceptions the code you're calling declares.

But, you could replace `MyException` with `Exception` in this code if you must.

---

There are libraries that provide a `Checked*` functional interfaces. [Vavr](http://www.vavr.io/) is one. Vavr's `CheckedConsumer.accept()` throws `Throwable`.

---

It may be easier to try and come up with a Consumer that simply doesn't throw checked exceptions. If you're in control of the exceptions, consider making them extend `RuntimeException`. Or catch them inside your consumers and rethrow wrapped in a `RuntimeException`.